# How to prevent heap filling up

Tags: cassandra, out-of-memory

Firstly forgive me for what might be a very naive question.
I am on a mission to identify the right nosql database for my project.
I was inserting and updating records in the table (column family) in highly concurrent fashion.

Then i encountered this.

```
INFO 11:55:20,924 Writing Memtable-scan_request@314832703(496750/1048576 serialized/live bytes, 8204 ops)
 INFO 11:55:21,084 Completed flushing /var/lib/cassandra/data/mykey/scan_request/mykey-scan_request-ic-14-Data.db (115527 bytes) for commitlog position ReplayPosition(segmentId=1372313109304, position=24665321)
 INFO 11:55:21,085 Writing Memtable-scan_request@721424982(1300975/2097152 serialized/live bytes, 21494 ops)
 INFO 11:55:21,191 Completed flushing /var/lib/cassandra/data/mykey/scan_request/mykey-scan_request-ic-15-Data.db (304269 bytes) for commitlog position ReplayPosition(segmentId=1372313109304, position=26554523)
 WARN 11:55:21,268 Heap is 0.829968311377531 full.  You may need to reduce memtable and/or cache sizes.  Cassandra will now flush up to the two largest memtables to free up memory.  Adjust flush_largest_memtables_at threshold in cassandra.yaml if you don't want Cassandra to do this automatically
 WARN 11:55:21,268 Flushing CFS(Keyspace='mykey', ColumnFamily='scan_request') to relieve memory pressure
 INFO 11:55:25,451 Enqueuing flush of Memtable-scan_request@714386902(324895/843149 serialized/live bytes, 5362 ops)
 INFO 11:55:25,452 Writing Memtable-scan_request@714386902(324895/843149 serialized/live bytes, 5362 ops)
 INFO 11:55:25,490 Completed flushing /var/lib/cassandra/data/mykey/scan_request/mykey-scan_request-ic-16-Data.db (76213 bytes) for commitlog position ReplayPosition(segmentId=1372313109304, position=27025950)
 WARN 11:55:30,109 Heap is 0.9017950505664833 full.  You may need to reduce memtable and/or cache sizes.  Cassandra will now flush up to the two largest memtables to free up memory.  Adjust flush_largest_memtables_at threshold in cassandra.yaml if you don't want Cassandra to do this automatically



java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Dumping heap to java_pid8849.hprof ...
Heap dump file created [1359702396 bytes in 105.277 secs]
 WARN 12:25:26,656 Flushing CFS(Keyspace='mykey', ColumnFamily='scan_request') to relieve memory pressure
 INFO 12:25:26,657 Enqueuing flush of Memtable-scan_request@728952244(419985/1048576 serialized/live bytes, 6934 ops)
```

Its to be noticed that i was able to insert & update around 6 million records before i got this. I am using cassandra on a single node. In-spite of the hint in the logs, i am not able to decide what config to change. I did check into the bin/cassandra shell script and i see they have done lots of manipulation before they came up with the -Xms & -Xmx values.

Kindly advice.

Comment: What is your heap size set to?  It will be printed on startup in Cassandra's logs.  How much memory does your server have?

Comment: The heap size is -Xms1024M -Xmx1024M -Xmn100M -Xss180k .
I am using a thin provisioned virtual machine with 2GB ram.
The logs advice to reduce memtable and cache size. Not sure where to do that. Please advice

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, you can run

```
ps -ef|grep cassandra
```

to see what -Xmx is set to in your Cassandra. The default values of -Xms and -Xmx are based on the amount of your system's memory.

Check this for details:
http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/1.2/index.html?pagename=docs&version=1.2&file=index#cassandra/operations/ops_tune_jvm_c.html

You can try to increase MAX_HEAP_SIZE (in conf/cassandra-env.sh) to see if the problem would go away.

For example, you can replace

```
MAX_HEAP_SIZE="${max_heap_size_in_mb}M"
```

with

```
MAX_HEAP_SIZE="2048M"
```

Comment: Could you please tell me how to reduce memtable and cache size.
My max heap can't be extended as my vm has only 2 gb ram.

Comment: Those settings are all in conf/cassandra.yaml. search for memtable_total_space_in_mb, key_cache_size_in_mb... By default some are commented out. Read comment in cassandra.yaml and Cassandra doc (the link I posted) for more explanation.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that tuning the Garbage Collector for Cassandra might solve the OOM error. Cassandra use Concurrent mark-and-sweep(CMS) JVM implementation for Garbage Collector when we use default settings.Most oftenly the CMS garbage collector would only start after the heap is almost fully populated. But the CMS process itself takes some time to finish and the problem is that the JVM runs out of space before the CMS process finished.We can set the percentage of used old generation space which triggers the CMS with following options in bin/cassandra.in.sh file under JAVA_OPTS variable

-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction={percentage} - This controls the percentage of the old generation when the CMS is triggered and we can set this bit lower value to hold until CMS process finished.

-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly - This parameter ensures the percentage is kept fixed

Also with the following options we can achieve incremental CMS

-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC \
-XX:+CMSIncrementalMode \
-XX:+CMSIncrementalPacing \
-XX:CMSIncrementalDutyCycleMin=0 \
-XX:+CMSIncrementalDutyCycle=10

We can increase the parallel CMS threads considering the number of cores of the CPU

-XX:ParallelCMSThreads={numberOfTreads}

Further we can tune the garbage collection for young generation for make the process optimum. Here we have to control the amount of re-used objects

1. Increasing the size of the young generation
2. Delay the young generation objects promotion for old generation

To achieve this we can set following parameters

1. -XX:NewSize={size} - Determine the size of the young generation
2. -XX:NewMaxSize={size} - This is the maximum size of the young generation
3. -Xmn{size} - Fix the maximum size
4. -XX:NewRatio={n} - Set the ratio of young generation to old generation

Before the objects are migrate to the old generation from young generation they are put in to phase called "young survior". So we can controll the migration of the objects to old generation using following parameters

1. -XX:SurvivorRatio={n} - ration of "young eden" to "young survivors"
2. -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold={age} Number of objects to be migrated to old generation