# How to improve read performance in cassandra

Tags: performance, cassandra, heap-memory, database-performance

facing OutOfMemoryError while retrieving data in CQL3.

Always prompt to heapsize is full [refered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17345063/how-to-prevent-heap-filling-up) this question but no Help.

So one way is to increase the RAM size of system and avoid this problem, but that sounds quit a weird solution, so two things how to increase the read performance and how to solve this OutOfMemoryError error?

Comment: Have you applied Datastax's tuning guidelines from http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/operations/ops_tune_jvm_c.html?

Comment: @DonBranson yes i tried.. if records are more then 200000 then above error is coming. i have 8 GB RAM and assuming this much RAM can retrieve more rows without any problem. people are retrieving data in tera-bites, so in that case what will be system configuration?